# Regex expression needed for currency field using jquery

Tags: regex

My amount field accepts `$0.00` (can accept any number along with the dollar sign , comma and decimal point but no special characters or alphabets). Need a regex expression for this condition.
Tried all other possible ways found in other links but not going through the condition.

```
if(/^\$([0-9]{1, 3}(\, [0-9]{3})*|([0-9]+))(\.[0-9]{2})?$/.test(amount))
```

For the above condition when I give the amount as $100.40 , it has to accept and enter the if condition but always goes inside the else part as invalid amount.

Can someone please help me out.

Comment: ...why not just use `<input type="number" />` (and use CSS to render a fixed `$` symbol)?

Comment: Please show a variety of input edge cases that should match and some input that shouldn't match. For example should `$000,001.00` match? Some quick help: escape the leading `$` and the dot.

Comment: Your regexp has a space after comma. Also, comma has no special meaning, you don't have to escape it.

Comment: Things tend to be easier if you take the dollar sign outside of the input field, e.g. `$<input ...>`

Comment: What's the point of expecting the end-user to format currency? Why do you wish to send thousand separators and currency symbols to the backend? By accepting these characters you're just making it unnecessarily difficult to perform arithmetic if need-be.

Answer (score 0):

The space between the comma and the following digit in the grouping section is causing the validation to fail.

Here's the corrected regular expression:

```js
/^\$([0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*|[0-9]+)(\.[0-9]{2})?$/
```

```js
if (/^\$([0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*|[0-9]+)(\.[0-9]{2})?$/.test(amount)) {
  console.log("Valid amount");
} else {
  console.log("Invalid amount");
}
```